# Trouble with Jquery ColorPicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im using [jQuery ColorPicker](http://vanderlee.github.io/colorpicker/) and i want to have a button that adds input to get more than one color, im doing this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $(".test").prepend('<input type="text" id="colorpicker-" value=""><br>');
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="test"></div>
<button id="btn1">Append text</button>
```

but when i click the button the little button on the right that show the popup is not showing...

if i put `<input type="text" id="colorpicker-full" value="fe9810">` works normally with the popup button...

Why is not working when I'm adding new inputs?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: @sheerforceits the first time that i use this, don't judge haha 
some styles are missing but the idea of my problem is there. http://jsfiddle.net/hood5e4w/

Comment: @Hook : try this : http://jsfiddle.net/hood5e4w/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vq6xqbbs/). Basically you need to set a new id for each input added. You can't set two or more tags with the same id. And after new input insert you need to call .colorpicker again for the new input tag.

The result code would be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        var newid=$(".test input").length;
        $(".test").prepend('<input type="text" id="colorpicker-'+newid+'" value=""><br>');
        $('#colorpicker-'+newid).colorpicker({
         parts:          'full',
         alpha:          true,
         showOn:         'both',
         buttonColorize: true,
         showNoneButton: true
        });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen your call to colorpicker, but I will suppose you are calling it once when the document is ready.

Because you are dynamically adding the elements with prepend, these new inputs are not bound to colorpicker (called onload) and it looks is not able to check it after that. So you should call it again inside.

You can do it in the way you were trying and you should call colorpicker to refresh it:

http://jsfiddle.net/LoLzoLyw/

```
$("#btn1").on('click', function(){

    $('<input type="text" id="your-id" class="colorpicker-full" value="fe9810"><br>').prependTo('.test');

    $('.colorpicker-full').colorpicker();

});
```

Or if you ask me, I think the best way is adding the input into the DOM dynamically (and also calling colorpicker):

http://jsfiddle.net/ud0a8cqa/2/

```
$("#btn1").on('click', function(){

    $("<br>").prependTo('.test');

    $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'text',
        id: 'your-id',
        class: 'colorpicker-full',
        value: 'fe9810'
    }).prependTo('.test').colorpicker();

});
```

By the way, I prefer to have this kind of jQuery elements in a common class instead of call them by ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
Only 2 Steps to add this one.
1] Add color JS file at given Download option

2] <script src="jscolor.js"></script>
   Color: <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567">
```

[Download demo](http://jscolor.com/)